# Python extend the __dict__ object with another dict

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class of `Person` and I want to assign new properties for each instance but I also want to keep track of said new properties, something like:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.props = {}
        
        for arg in kwargs:
            self.props[arg] = self.__dict__[arg] = kwargs[arg]
```

But for example, the following code would show why this doesn't gets me what I need:

```
person = Person(name='Tomer')
person.props['name'] = 'Michael'
print(person.name)
# >> 'Tomer'
```

How can I keep a reference to the added attributes with the option to edit their source?

Comment: What is your `props` dictionary for? What does it do that `__dict__` doesn't already do?

Comment: You *could* just do `self.props = self.__dict__`.  then simply `self.props.update(**kwargs)` But *why* would you want to do this? What is the point of `self.props`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class P(dict):
   def __init__(self, *k, **kwargs):
      self.__dict__ = self
      super().__init__(*k, **kwargs)

p = P(name = "me", age = 40)
>>> p['name'] == p.name == "me"
True
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `__dict__` object is the dictionary object of your class or instance. There is no need to directly manipulate that, because the class can handle setting the attributes itself. You can simply set the attributes directly without the need of an intermediate `props`:

```py
class Person: 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        for k, v in kwargs.items(): 
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

Then you can just say:

```py
person = Person(name='Tomer')
print(person.name)  # output: "Tomer"
person.name = 'Michael'
print(person.name)  # output: "Michael"
```

I'm not sure if that is what you want, though.

Comment: Nitpick: `__dict__` isn't a *representation* of the instance, it is the actual instance namespace

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer, you can just set the `__getattr__` function on the `Person` class which would execute when access to a variable that is not in the class and parent class is accessed.

Comment: That's one way. A sneakier way is what I've suggested in my answer.